# Набор битов данных о цвете с экрана монитора в массив c#

Tags: c#, массивы, графика, скриншот

есть код для создания скриншота экрана.

```
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width , Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height );
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
printscreen.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

В частности меня интересует момент с классом Graphics и методом CopyFromScreen
В документации говориться, что:

```
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
```

Метод CopyFromScreen - Выполняет перемещение набора битов данных о цвете с экрана на поверхность рисования объекта Graphics.

Вопрос следующий. Каким образом можно получить этот набор битов сразу в виде массива и не производить лишние манипуляции с графикой?
Спасибо.

Comment: Во-первых, вместо `MemoryStream` пишите сразу в файловый или сетевой поток, в зависимости от того, на диск пишете или по сети передаёте данные.

Comment: Вряд ли в c# есть прямой доступ к видеопамяти, используйте CopyFromScreen =)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как я понял из условий, оно подлежит редактированию перед сохранением.

Comment: Попробуйте применить [Bitmap.LockBits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8). Через указатель получите доступ сразу к сырым байтам. Но без `CopyFromScreen` не обойтись.